# How to concatenate values from multiple rows using Pandas?

Tags: pandas

[image: Screenshot of data table]

In the screenshot, 'Ctrl' column contains a key value. I have two duplicate rows for OTC-07 which I need to consolidate. I would like to concat the rest of column values for OTC-07. i.e, OTC-07 should have Type A,B and Assertion a,b,c,d after consolidation.. Can anyone help me on this? :o

Comment: Please do not post data or code screenshots. Replace them with actual data. We are not going to retype your data.

Comment: It is better to post your data as test instead of image. It is quite easy actually !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a dataframe of given structure:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Ctrl': ['OTC-05', 'OTC-06', 'OTC-07', 'OTC-07', 'OTC-08'],
    'Type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', np.NaN],
    'Assertion': ['a,b,c', 'c,b', 'a,c', 'b,c,d', 'a,b,c']
})

df
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Then replace NaN values with empty strings:

```
df = df.replace(np.NaN, '', regex=True)
```

Then group by column 'Ctrl' and aggregate columns 'Type' and 'Assertion'. Please not that assertion aggregation is a bit tricky as you need not a simple concatenation, but sorted list of unique letters:

```
df.groupby(['Ctrl']).agg({
    'Type': ','.join, 
    'Assertion': lambda x: ','.join(list(sorted(set(','.join(x).split(',')))))
})
```

Output:

[image: Output]